# mysql subquery returns more than 1 row query error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have many tables for messaging system. But i can't send query to mysql.

```
SELECT 
            messages_list.IDUSER,
            messages_list.IDPAGE,
            messages_list.IDUSER,
            messages_list.v_readed,
            messages_list.IDUSER,
            messages_texts.v_text,
            messages_texts.v_time,
            messages_subjects.v_title,
            user_photos.v_photoURL,
            user.v_sex,
            (SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER)
        FROM 
            messages_texts,
            user
        INNER JOIN user_photos ON user_photos.ID=user.IDPHOTO AND user_photos.v_active='1' 
        INNER JOIN messages_list ON messages_list.IDUSER=717306 AND messages_list.v_active='1'
        INNER JOIN messages_subjects ON messages_list.IDSUBJECT=messages_subjects.ID
        INNER JOIN messages_users ON messages_users.IDSUBJECT=messages_subjects.ID AND messages_users.IDUSER=user.ID
        WHERE
            messages_users.IDUSER<>717306  
        GROUP BY messages_subjects.ID
        ORDER BY messages_list.ID
    )\n: (Subquery returns more than 1 row)
```

Where is the problem??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this subquery:

```
        (SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER)
```

It is nested in a `select` statement, so it should return only one value.  The `where` clause consists of just the `IDUSER` value.  This will return "true" whenever this is not `0` (presuming the field is an integer).  So, it will basically return all users.

Presumably, you want an/the `IDPHOTO` for a specific user:

```
        (SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER = user.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery cannot return more than one row.This query:

```
SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER
```

returns more than one row which it cannot do. You need to limit it to one row only either by using a `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER LIMIT 1
```

Or by using a specific key:

```
SELECT IDPHOTO FROM user WHERE messages_list.IDUSER WHERE id=1
```